# How do you change MediumTopAppBar (Material 3 Jetpack Compose) to always stay collapsed and not expand?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use the `MediumTopAppBar`, but I want it to be able to play around with it so that for certain screens it can expand/collapse, but on other screens I just want it to be collapsed.

I tried playing around with the scroll behavior but so far I can't get it to stay collapsed. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can control `TopAppBar` scroll behavior with `canScroll` param of `enterAlwaysScrollBehavior` function. And if you want it to be collapsed, set `TopAppBarState.heightOffset` to be equal to `TopAppBarState.heightOffsetLimit`.

```
var canScroll by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(true) }
val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(
    canScroll = { canScroll },
)
```

To collapse and pin:

```
scrollBehavior.state.heightOffset = scrollBehavior.state.heightOffsetLimit
canScroll = false
```

To unpin:

```
canScroll = true
```

[image: Example]

Comment: where to insert this recommended code?

Comment: That depends on your app and where your `TopAppBar` and `scrollBehavior` are. @Erhy

Comment: I solved my problem with 
enableEdgeToEdge( navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.dark(0x7F000000 ) )